# Where are the oil platforms in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, oil-gas

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Tower_(oil_platform)) I found the coordinates of the [Devil's Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Tower_(oil_platform)), which is an oil platform in the Gulf of Mexico. The coordinates are 28°12′32″N, 88°44′15″W.

When I enter these coordinates into Google Earth, I see just the empty ocean, no gas platform.

I tried to do the same with some other oil platforms, such as [Statfjord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statfjord_oil_field) at 61°15′20″N, 1°51′14″E, and again I see nothing.

What is the reason for this? Is it just that the satellite images acquired of the oceans are low resolution?

Comment: Acquiring full-resolution images of the ocean is an easy way to triple the amount of images you need to capture and store.

Comment: satellite imagery on that sort of scale is generally stitched - shots from multiple satellite flyovers, amalgamated into one. year before last, this effect caused the loch ness monster to appear in a Google Earth image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not see oil platforms in oceans because Google Earth shows the underwater terrain (bathymetry). In ocean area you see the seafloor. In land or coast area you see an aerial or satellite image.

Comment: Indeed; it wouldn't be a good use of resources to photograph thousands of square miles of endless ocean from above :)

Comment: How come folks saw [Sail Rock](http://www.theverge.com/2016/6/20/11978930/sea-monster-google-maps-facebook-rock-fake) and thought it was a Sea Monster? (On closer look I guess it's just close enough to the Coast for Aerial)

Answer (score 17):

As Jens said, Google Earth doesn't show you satellite or aerial images for ocean areas. However, the European Space Agency provides global imagery from its [Sentinel 2](http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/) mission, which covers the oceans and has a high enough resolution to show oil platforms:

[image]
[Sentinel-2A imagery of Devil's Tower](http://postcards.sentinel-hub.com/v1/wms/b182f15c-a041-400f-a285-0c269710be5a?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=TRUE_COLOR&BBOX=-9852732,3271446,-9849700,3274478&MAXCC=0&WIDTH=640&HEIGHT=640&gain=1.1&FORMAT=image/jpeg&bgcolor=00000000&transparent=1&TIME=2016-04-27/2016-08-16)

[image]
[Sentinel-2A imagery of platforms in the Statfjord oil field](http://www.sentinel-hub.com/apps/postcards#x=248698%2By=8670589%2Bs=13%2Blayers=TRUE_COLOR%2Bmaxcc=7%2Bgain=1.1%2Btime=2016-07-11/2016-10-10%2BshowImage)

Answer (score 1):

These are all out of date. Yes, you can see oil rigs off the coast of California. Actually for the past few years. They are in lines of 4 Starting around Santa Barbara.

[image: oil rigs off the coast of California]

Comment: when you say `These are all out of date` to what are you referring?